# How can I get the category of a term by its QID?

Tags: wikidata, dbpedia

I obtained entities(and their QIDs) and the category data from Wikidata, but cannot connect the two.

Here is what an entity entry is like:

> `<http://wikidata.dbpedia.org/resource/Q100000001> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/alias> "Franklin School"@tl .`

and here is a category data entry:

> `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/!Oka_Tokat> <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Television_shows_set_in_the_Philippines> .`

We can see that the two dataset cannot be linked by a foreign key.

I know that I cant extract the page of an entity by its QID, but I wonder if there is a table containing the QID-category mapping?

Comment: These seem to be from DBpedia's rendering of Wikidata/Wikipedia, and not from Wikidata itself. Wikidata does not, generally speaking, contain Wikipedia category information. You might have more luck asking this as a DBpedia question.